# Rails association - how to add the 'has_many' object to the 'owner'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

In my app, a `user` has many `score_cards` and a `score_card` belongs to a `user`

The question is, whenever I create a new `score_card`, ie, `ScoreCardsController.create` gets called, how do I add this newly created `score_card` to the `current_user` (I'm using devise, so `current_user` is a valid `User` object).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
current_user.score_cards << score_card
```

OR

```
score_card.user = current_user
score_card.save
```

Comment: I personally prefer the first one, but it is up to you :)

Comment: I believe these are not actually equivalent because `<<` will save the association (without having to explicitly call `User#save`).

Comment: You do not need to call current_user.save. You can just call "current_user.score_cards << score_card"

Comment: I would upvote this answer if the first solution didn't include a redundant save.

Comment: ... And indeed now have. :)

Answer (score 13):

Use the association builder method:

```
current_user.score_cards.build(params[:score_card])
```

Alternatively to `build` you can use `create` or `create!` if you don't care about the validations in the controller.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to throw this out there in case anyone is looking for a way to add multiple objects to an associated object:

```
score_cards = ScoreCard.all
current_user.score_cards << score_cards
```

No need to current_user.save

Comment: Thanks for making note of this!  I've always been doing an unnecessary save afterward.